# Facebook email permission ios

Tags: ios, facebook, email, permissions

very confused  - have made several apps which login with Facebook  - latest one doesn't work -

in all my apps i have a FBLoginView in storyboard

then in ViewDidLoad

```
self.facebookLogin.readPermissions =  @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];


[self.facebookLogin setDelegate:self];
```

along with all the basic delegate methods - all the methods are called correctly

however it only seems to request public_profile and not anything else - like

```
2014-06-02 23:35:33.994 TheCooKPot[3997:60b] profile {
"first_name" = Karen;
gender = female;
id = 1397217637233431;
"last_name" = Shepardstein;
link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1397217637233431/";
locale = "en_GB";
"middle_name" = Amhcefbdegja;
name = "Karen Amhcefbdegja Shepardstein";
timezone = 1;
"updated_time" = "2014-06-02T22:34:00+0000";
verified = 0;
```

}

unlike all my other apps which get an email address

any ideas?? have set my apps up identically in Facebook and configured the same in plist

Comment: Are you using a different version of the Facebook SDK to what you've used before? If so, which FB SDK version are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the Graph API v2.0, and your app was registered after April 30th 2014. Then, if you want to use more than the `basic_profile` permission, you need to get you app reviewed by Facebook.

Have a look here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login for a description of the process.

Comment: Actually, Tobi, thats not needed in this case. Developers can use the public_profile, email and user_friends permissions without review by Facebook. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

Comment: Simon, I know, but he didn't write if he's using his admin/dev user or another one... And if he's using another user, afaik the problem which is described will occur.

Comment: @Tobi: thanks dear, I face some issue in graph api for posting on behalf, could you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030846/posting-in-group-on-behalf-of-user-using-facebook-graph-api

Comment: @tobi - What I mean is that an app can request the public_profile, email and user_friends permissions from people without needing to be reviewed by Facebook.

Review is only required for permissions beyond these three.