# Not able to get user_photos permission with another user facebook id

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I am developing an app by which I can download album's photo of authenticated user. If I Login with my Facebook developer mail then I get list of albums. But when I am try to login with another user email id (except email id which is used for creating app)I am successfully authenticated but in list of permissions user_photos permission is missing(But I include at the time of authentication) while my app is public on Facebook server.

That's why I am getting blank JSON when requesting album list.

data{[]}

Comment: How are you adding the permissions? Show some code

Comment: my code works fine @Sahil when using other apps credentials.

Comment: I got answer from @Tobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour in v2.0. See my answer here: [Facebook email permission ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004495/facebook-email-permission-ios/24008801#24008801)

If your app was created after April 30th 2014, you'll need to get your app reviewed by Facebook to gather more than the basic permissions.

See also

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_login
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: Thanks @Tobi, Now I can test my app on other apps created before. But really this LOL I spend whole day for this problem.