# Publish permission returns "installed" and "public_profile" as requested permission

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I requested **@"publish_stream",@"publish_checkins"** permissions. But when I print the active session's permissions, It displays **"installed", "public_profile"** as requested permissions. Thus I am unable to use below condition and it opens login screen again on active session.

```
if([[[FBSession activeSession] permissions] indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] == NSNotFound || [[[FBSession activeSession] permissions] indexOfObject:@"publish_checkins"] == NSNotFound)
```

This was observed in facebook sdk 3.14.0. I was using facebook sdk 3.7.1 which works just fine.

What am I doing wrong and How could I resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your app was registered after April 30th 2014, you're using Graph API v2.0. To use non-basic permission with non-admin users, you'll need to get your app reviewed by facebook.

Have a look at my answer here: [Facebook email permission ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004495/facebook-email-permission-ios/24008801#24008801)

Comment: But my app registered on 2013 and I am using V3.7.1.